# Grouping consecutive numbers in a list when group count greater than 2

Tags: c#

So in addition to below, i want to implement a joker value that can be any value.

Let’s say we have numbers (3,8,5,6,J,2,9)

And the output should be (5,6,J)

I mean J in the list should act like 7 and this will be grouped.

Is there a way to do that?

++++

I am trying to find a solution to below code posted by Mauricio Scheffer.

Output;

```
group 2  
group 4  
group 7,8,9
group 5,6
```

What I need: only groups 7,8,9and not others.

I mean when the function finds consecutive numbers it should only group consecutive numbers when group count greater than 2.

Any ideas/help please?

```
static class Example
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> list)
    {
        var group = new List<int>();
  
        foreach (var i in list)
        {
            if (group.Count == 0 || i - group[group.Count - 1] == 1)
            {
                 group.Add(i);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return group;
                group = new List<int> { i };
            }
      }
}

class Program
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         var groups = new[] {2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6}.GroupConsecutive();

         foreach (var g in groups)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("group: {0}", string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()));
             Console.ReadLine();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: So you're looking for groups [`.Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-5.0) the [`.Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=net-5.0) is `> 2`?

Comment: I not sure that's the same thing, i can find the groups .Count() is > 2 but that is not workable unfo. I need to prevent grouping .Count() < 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this ([Net.Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VhM7tx)):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
static class Example
{
   public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> GroupConsecutive(this IEnumerable<int> list)
   {
      var group = new List<int>();  
      var j = 1;
      foreach (var i in list)
      {
        
        if (j != list.Count() && (group.Count == 0 || i - group[group.Count - 1] == 1))
        {
            group.Add(i);
        }
        else if(j == list.Count()) {
            if (group.Count == 0 || i - group[group.Count - 1] == 1)
                group.Add(i);
            if (group.Count > 2) {
                yield return group;
            }
        }
        else
        {
           if (group.Count > 2) {
             var groupCopy = new List<int>(group);
             group = new List<int>() {i};
             yield return groupCopy;
           } else {
             group = new List<int>() {i};
           }
        }
        j++;
      }
   }
}

public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    var groups = new[] {2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 5, 6, 7,12}.GroupConsecutive();

    foreach (var g in groups)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("group: {0}", string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()));
         Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: seems working but if we don't put yield return group after foreach loop it doesn't find second consecutive group. But anyhow i put there again yield return group inside if .group.Count() >=3 and it works. Thank you very much .

Comment: @Catklysm, actually, it doesn't find the last  consecutive group

Comment: Quite right, I fixed it to include the last group too.

Comment: @Catklysm, don't forget to accept working answers! Cheers!

Comment: @Athanasios Kataras, thank you very much..Sorry i wasn't online.

Comment: @Athanasios, when i try to add second condition ( like (i=group[group.Count -1] also group it seperately), i couldn't get the correct result. Do you have any idea?